# How to properly rename WinForms controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I've just started working on my first GUI app (Windows Forms) using C# with Visual Studio 2012, and I'm baffled by the IDE's handling of the Name property of all controls. Here's an example:

-I add a RichTextBox onto my form using the Toolbox

-The (Name) property is automatically set to a default value of: richTextBox1

-I change the value of (Name) to something else such as: richTextBoxResults

-When I try to use it (eg. within my Form1() method) the IDE thinks that it doesn't exist

-This line causes a compilation error: richTextBoxResults.AppendText("a");

Error   1
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Foo.Form1.richTextBoxResults'

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem, it very much knows it exists.  Because it is telling you that you are using it wrong.  You are writing bad code, it doesn't have anything to do with the IDE.  We can't see the code.

Comment: I think the fault is of your part, you should post some code to show us how you use it. the IDE (especially Express Edition) works great to me, there are some `format errors (underline wrong)` in VS 2010 Ultimate but it compiles OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at two things.

1)  Make sure you have saved the form in question
2)  When issues arise - try rebuilding the solution (with compiling code).

This will usually trigger a refresh of the code to ensure it can see it.  If you are still having problems - then you are trying to access the control from the wrong location or you have the name misspelled  (it is case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name from PropertyWindow and Save it before accessing it in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) a try? It can take care of this kind of problem for you, and furthermore, help you write good code.